# Mit App Inventor 2 keyboard pop up automatically

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application where I need that the keyboard pops up automatically without the need to click on the textbox in MIT APP INVENTOR 2.

I tried to focus on the textbox but it didn't work.

I created a screen2 and added a text box named TextBox1. Then in the blocks I added When Screen2.Initialize => call TextBox1.RequestFocus procedure. And it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Like the Activity that is called when moving to the specific page where you want to display the keyboard. Also, for me it sounds like you want to auto-focus onload on a specific element.

Comment: I created a screen2 and added a text box named TextBox1.  Then in the blocks i added When Screen2.Initialize => call TextBox1.RequestFocus procedure.  And it didn't work

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and I am going to share it with you.

Just download the taifun tool extension and use it. Actually, it has the show keyboard option.

Answer (score 0):

First choose the textbox to write in and then set the focus to that textbox and the keyboard will appear automatically. If don't you can try a actititystarter.

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In activity starter i don't know how to map the intents. I am new to MIT APP INVENTOR.  Thanks in advance.